# Accented Characters in Folder Paths from StdOut from icacls causing problems

Tags: regex, vbscript, stdout, wsh, icacls

I'm writing a vbscript to tidy up permissions on the various Windows file shares, and hit into  a problem I've not yet been able to overcome.

This part of the script first runs a basic icacls to pull back the current permissions for the path (obtained from reading a text file (and yes unicode and yes I had the TriStateTrue set), which could be a folder or file (I deal with that later in the script).

```
strFolderPath = chr(34) & strFolderPathRaw & chr(34)

Set icacls = oshell.Exec("icacls " & strFolderPath)
Do While icacls.Status = 0
 WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

'Process through permissions for Folder Path
Do Until icacls.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
strPermission = icacls.StdOut.ReadLine
etc.
```

Now, if you run icacls, you'll know the first line contains the path you just gave it, then the first ACL entry, the following entries are just on their own but indented with spaces to match the length of the path, e.g.

```
D:\Folder\Folder\File.doc NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
                          DOMAIN\Domain Admins:(F)

D:\Folder\Folder\Folder\File.doc NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
                                 DOMAIN\Domain Admins:(F)
```

So I used some regex replace to firstly remove out the path, and cut out all the double spaces to just a single space, and ignore the first character in the string (which is a space), as I couldn't just remove all spaces as "Domain Admins" has a space in it.

```
strPermission = Replace(strPermission,strFolderPathRaw, "")

objRegEx.Pattern = "[ ]{2,}"
strPermission = objRegEx.Replace(strPermission, " ")

objRegEx.Pattern = "^.{1}([^\n\r:]+:+.+)$"
strPermission = objRegEx.Replace(strPermission, "$1")
```

Pretty clever I thought... until some overseas shares ruined my plans, and had folder names like:
Telegramm für X

which when I checked the StdOut, I saw it being instead:
Telegramm f?r X

Hence no match, not replaced/removed, curses. After many, many hours googling and trial & error, I still have not got over this problem. Has anyone else come across this and got a working solution/fix ? Thank you.

Comment: Both cmd and cscript have unicode options. `cmd /?` and `cscript /?`.

Comment: I'd recommend against shelling out to `icacls` for this task. Parsing commandline output is just a bad way of doing this. Unneccessary too. You can read permissions with VBScript and WMI alone (take a look at my script [`AuditACLs`](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/auditacls.shtml)). An even better approach would be using PowerShell, if that's an option for you. In PowerShell you could easily traverse a folder tree with `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` and read ACLs with the `Get-Acl` cmdlets.

Comment: @phd443322 yep, I've tried the unicode options for cscript //U and cmd /u by using " Set icacls = oshell.Exec("cmd /U /C icacls " & strFolderPath)" instead, but hasn't made a difference.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Ideally don't want to have to write another 706 lines of code, had thought I was finally done. Fairly new to powershell, and usually found you need a later version or module that's not there to do anything I've had to, but of course this is file permissions, so even powershell 1.0 should be able to cope. I feel a dreaded rewrite of the whole script for Powershell coming on.. *groan*.